# DSE create core with coreOptionsInline

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-search

I am trying to set docValues as true on all the fields on the table to enable Sorting.

> dsetool create_core keyspace.cf generateResources=true reindex=true coreOptionsInline=generate_docvalues_for_fields:'*'

But I am seeing the below error:

> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException:
>   while scanning an alias  in 'string', line 1, column 32:
>       generate_docvalues_for_fields: *
>
> expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found but found

how do we generate SOLR core with docValues enabled for all fields?

Answer (score 3):

Use "" to surround: 
`coreOptionsInline="generate_docvalues_for_fields:'*'"`

Comment: I don't see the docValues=true being set when using the CURL locahost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=keyspace.cf&generateResources=true&coreOptionsInline="generate_docvalues_for_fields:%27*%27" but see this option set when using the dsetool. Am I giving the options correctly

Comment: I think this is purely dsetool option, will not work with Solr API CREATE

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. Unfortunately our current design was to have API create for generating the core.

Comment: as a workaround I can suggest using `dsetool infer_solr_schema` with coreOptionsInline and pass schema to http API :-) Not sure if it is an option for you.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. we are generating the schema now, pretty much like you suggested.